# How do I make a Win32 PE executable with included resources and specific VERSIONINFO information with an x86 assembler?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, exe, versioninfo

What tools would I use to create a Windows 95 and NT compatible executable that includes specific resources (.rsrc data) and specific VERSIONINFO data (such as the "CompanyName" and the "FileDescription") and assemble x86 code?

Would FASM work?

Edit: Thanks for the correction, Jens. Question edited.

Comment: A frontal lobotomy first, in order to want to do this? ;)

Comment: I've already had one, Ken. ;)

Comment: It might be useful to add the names of tools you have or can use (e.g. MASM, NASM, etc etc).

Comment: The standard SDK tool is rc.exe to compile a resource script (.rc file) to a .res file.  It needs to contain a VERSIONINFO resource. The linker embeds the .res file into the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CompanyName** and **FileDescription** are not attributes of the PE header, but of the [VERSIONINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) resource, so you wouldn't need custom PE headers.

FASM has excellent means of [including resource data](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32#1.8).

Comment: Note for the record: The "resource data" link in this answer also includes information about using VERSIONINFO in FASM.